# Why hadoop daemon stop immediately?

Tags: java, hadoop, process, daemon

I use hadoop 1.2.1. After I do `start-all.sh`, and `jps` command, all daemons run normally, like this :

```
21106 JobTracker
20718 NameNode
22528 DataNode
21254 TaskTracker
21017 SecondaryNameNode
22892 Jps
```

But after 5 or 10 second, I run `jps` again and some daemon stop immediately one by one. Sometimes the datanode stops, but sometimes jobtracker stops. I don't know why this happens.

Comment: You will get the error details in log files. so copy paste your logs.

Comment: Firstly thanks a lot.... where can I get the logs? Is that the path that I configure in hadoop.tmp.dir ?

Answer (score 0):

Hadoop daemon writes log to $HADOOP_HOME/logs folder by default if you are using apache installation. With CDH, the log location is under /var/log/hadoop-***.

In your case, you should looks at the log folder here: `which start-all.sh`..\logs : *namenode*.log  *jobtracker*.log, etc.